# (Done) Why is any question about security clearance closed as "Legal Advice"?

Tags: discussion, specific-question, reopen-request

I came across [this question today](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/60715/security-clearances-and-travel), and I am flabbergasted at the reason for closing the question.

Security clearances are permitted by and obtained from the US Government.  Companies have little involvement in the process.  This is a fair and reasonable question I've heard asked in a variety of forms by fellow applicants over the years, and it applies to anyone who will ever apply for security clearance.

Comment: Question is now open again

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I agree that the question is neither company-specific nor asking for legal advice. I suspect the sentence *"I am not sure what level of clearance I will need for the job."* made it seem job-specific. I have removed that sentence, added the [united-states](https://workplace.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/united-states) tag (based on Monica's answer and your explanation here), and made some other edits.

<s>I won't cast the binding reopen vote, but if it gets 4 reopen votes, I will cast the 5th one.</s> Question has been reopened now.

Answer (score 7):

This is exactly what I've been railing against.  "I don't understand it, so it must be off topic".

This might not surprise people, but I know about security clearances as well.

Voted to reopen.

Comment: also voted to reopen

Comment: Thank you.  I don't understand how the 5 people who voted to close that question can be moderators.  I spend a _lot_ more time on StackExchange sites than my lowly reputation implies, and this is far from the first time I've seen a question closed in a harsh way that alienates members of the community.  1 of those 5 is quite rude on a regular basis.  SO and SE are effectively without peer, and so when you're rejected from asking a good question here, it leaves a meaningful feeling of frustration and despair.

Comment: @pbarranis The 5 people who voted to close are not moderators. Only one of them is, and he too became a moderator about a year *after* the question was closed. Moderators have a diamond next to their user name. Our community does tend to close a lot of questions, which is a concern raised before, and which we are trying to address.